# std::function lambda optimization

Tags: c++, memory-management, lambda, c++14, std-function

`std::function` is known to have performance issues because it may do heap allocations. Admitted, if you are being 100% honest, one heap allocation should hardly be a problem in most cases... but let's just assume doing a heap allocation is undesirable or forbidding in a particular scenario. Maybe we're doing a few million callbacks and don't want a few million heap allocations for that, whatever.

So... we want to avoid that heap allocation.

The Dr. Dobbs article [Efficient Use of Lambda Expressions and std::function](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059?pgno=2) gives a recommendation on optimizing the use of `std::function` by taking advantage of the small object optimization that is recommended by the standard and implemented in every mainstream standard library.

The article goes into length explaining how the standard library must copy the functor since the `std::function` object might outlive the original functor (though you can use `std::ref` if you are sure it doesn't), which would be bad mojo. Also, captures need to be copied, and here is the problem: The exact type of closure (or its size) is not known beforehand as it could be any type of closure with any number of captures, so some compromise must be made. Up to a certain size, the captures will be saved in a store inside the `function` object, and beyond that, it will be dynamically allocated. The store is small, anywhere from 12 to 16 bytes, so assuming a 64-bit build, a maximum of two pointers (not counting the actual function pointer).

Dr. Dobbs thus recommends (and several other sites pick up that advice, seemingly without much of an objection) capturing a reference to a struct that holds references to what you actually want to capture. That way, you only capture one reference, which is just perfect, since it will always fit into the small object store.

How does that work? The assumption which made copying stuff around necessary in the first place was that the `function` object *may outlive the scope of the original closure*. Which means, of course, that it *also* outlives the structure that it holds a reference to, as well as anything referenced from inside that struct.

How is this supposed to work? And since I can't see how it could possibly work, is there a better well-known recipe to address this?  (one that doesn't reference invalid objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's supposed to work if the function object does outlive its calling function (and you're capturing references to objects that are on the stack).

In many practical cases the function object is used locally and will not outlive its caller and then you can avoid the heap allocation (but then again, the compiler might be able to optimize the references and the entire `struct` technique is probably not necessary).

Here's a simple [test](https://ideone.com/YmanBB) which compiles but crashes (tested on clang in C++14 mode.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that the article wasn't clearly enough. (I'm the author.)

The advised technique is indeed **not** supposed to work when the `std::function` object outlives the scope of the original closure in which case you **must not** use `std::ref` and must pay the price of copying and, potentially, making a heap allocation.

The point of the article is this: **when there's no lifetime issue** (a case which, as [nimrodm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23388/nimrodm) pointed [out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349872/1137388) is quite common), a user can pass this information to `std::function` for its constructor to *somehow* take the closure object by reference instead of by value. Obviously, the user cannot magically and punctually change the signature of `std::function`'s constructor for one particular call. That's where `std::reference_wrapper` and `std::ref` come in. The client passes a `std::reference_wrapper` (created by `std::ref`) object to `std::function`'s constructor. Then, what gets copied is this object which is small and should fit in the small-object-optimisation buffer and acts as a "*reference*" to the original closure object.

In [here](https://quick-bench.com/q/8-IuDhoIPK6hKVFmD5Zq2r_WZ_s) you can see impact on the performance of `std::function` construction (sure this is just one point of consideration amongst many others). In this example the closure object contains 3 `double`s and using `std::ref` makes the construction 7.5 times faster (YMMV):

[image]

One can inspect the generated assembly by clicking on the "Assembly" tab of the link above. A notable difference between the two versions is that the slower one contains this line:

```
callq  404430 <operator new(unsigned long)@plt>
```

This confirms that there's a call to `operator new` which is absent from the faster alternative.

Comment: @CassioNerri, the link does not work anymore! Can you point me to it?
I am really curious in finding out what are the benefits of std::function_ref if a small object optimization is already available in std::function!

Comment: @GrimFandango You're right. Sadly DrDobbs is dead and the link no longer works. Tip (useful in general but especially in this case): Try the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/). If someone has ever saved the original link there, then the content can be recovered. Just paste the link in the search bar and wait. (The site is very slow.) If a page is found, then a calendar will mark all dates on which people have saved the page. Click on any of them. (Not on a very recent one since page will be from the time DrDodds was dead.) (1/2)

Comment: Here are the links for the page saved on 18 Feb 2015: [page 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218165404/https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059) and [page 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20141218094557/http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/efficient-use-of-lambda-expressions-and/232500059?pgno=2). Again, be patient because the site is slow. But it might be a life saver! (2/2)